# Make tab labels stretch to full width in material design for angular

Tags: angular-material

I would like to get tabs to stretch to the full width of their parent div. Anyone know how to do this?

```
<div class="tabs-header">
    <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Signup">Content 1</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Login">Content 2</mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

As of now it looks like this:

[image]

I did some research it looks like there used to be a way to do this with something like `<md-stretch-tabs>` but that doesn't seem to be a feature and there is no documentation on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after much research I found the answer: the labels can be targeted using the css class `mat-tab-label` however, since they are overlay components they cannot be styled in the component itself and the styles need to be on the global style sheet as explained here: 
https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles
There are additional solutions there as well. The css I actually used:

```
.mat-tab-label {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You actually don't need to use global css. Instead you can use `<ng-template>` to define your label (example in the docs) and then style the `label` tag using component css (no global style or `::ng-deep`). eg. I had a need for a miniimum width `mat-tab-group label { min-width: 160px; }`

Comment: In the link you provided: "Avoid any custom styles or overrides on internal elements within a Angular Material components." By now we are victim of that practice, after migration to MDC.

Answer (score 77):

Also, you can use `mat-stretch-tabs` property

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
     <mat-tab label="Signup">Content 1</mat-tab>
     <mat-tab label="Login">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Note that in the old AngularJS material this had properties such as 'always', 'never' which it doesn't have anymore. If you're interested in the css that is invoked it is quite simple - https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.scss

Comment: And also https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tabs/tab-group.scss

Comment: question: this works, but how did you find this attribute?

Comment: @wooldridgetm you can't find this attribute in the API but it's in the [material example](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples)

Comment: @Wandrille you are right, but I don't understand why its not in the API docks

Comment: it shows pagination when i switch to second tab. and there are only 2 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that can be applied at the component level or global is to add the following CSS:

```
.mat-tab-labels {
     justify-content: space-around;
     display: flex;
}
```

Or, if you are using tailwind:

```
.mat-tab-labels {
     @apply justify-around 
     @apply flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

had to use ng deep for my app:

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

old question, but this is how I managed to achieve it

```
  ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label .mat-tab-label-content {

        width: 20px; // I have 5 tabs
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working for me only with absolute pixel size

```
.mat-tab-label {
  width: 300px;
}
```

and not in percent

```
.mat-tab-label {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Working with Angular/Material 7.1.0+

Comment: You need to set mat-tab-nav-bar to width:100% first.